# Error: error getting chaincode code fabcar: failed to determine platform type: Unknown chaincodeType: UNDEFINED

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain

I am new to Hyperledger Fabric and going thru their study tutorial https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html .
Issue : I made changes in query.js and invoke.js to replace local host with my IP Address which I reverted back to original . Now when I run startFabric.sh script , I am getting following error : " Error: error getting chaincode code fabcar: failed to determine platform type: Unknown chaincodeType: UNDEFINED " .
I have googled the issue whole day but still unable to solve . Please let me know how I may solve this issue .

Answer (score 2):

You aren't specifying a chaincode type, the command is `./startFabric.sh <chaincode type>` which you can specify as something like `javascript` or `golang`

Comment: I did add javascript after ./startFabric.sh .  As per Hyperledger fabric documentation - "Once npm install completes, everything is in place to run the application. For this tutorial, you’ll primarily be using the application JavaScript files in the fabcar/javascript directory"
But actually there is no Javascript file ,thats why ./startFabric.sh javascript is not working . The issue was with Fabric version 1.4 release. I updated to the latest Fabric version and the issue cease to exist .